# more precise way to compute X / Y * Z

Tags: floating-point

I want to compute a more precise result to a very simple equation, namely x / y * z.  Are there any tricks to get a more precise result such as ordering the operations in a particular way or computing intermediate values a la Kahan summation?

Comment: Are x, y, and z all of similar absolute value or is there one of them that is significantly larger or smaller than the others?

Comment: Is `x / y * z` the entire operation? If it is, there really isn't much room left to improve the precision. Assuming IEEE, evaluating `x / y * z` in any order is probably going to be within 1 ulp of the correct value.

Comment: @DanielPryden: How would a difference in magnitudes affect the accuracy? Multiplication and division are invariant under exponent adjustments up to the bounds of the format. E.g., `x/y` has exactly the same relative error as `(x*1024)/y` as long as the product does not overflow to infinity.

Comment: There are possibilities, but you should state more about your problem. Is a fused multiply-add (FMA) available? How much more precision do you want? Computing a more precise result may require several times as much compute time. Is that tolerable? Do you know anything about the particular values involved? Dekker multiplication can be used to get an exact product (in two terms whose mathematical sum would equal the product), but then remains the problem of improving the division.